# Battery connector on XOOM2 Media edition tablet motherboard

Tags: identification, connector

Can you help me identify what kind of connector is used on the motherboard of the XOOM2 motorola media edition tablet? This connector has broken and I need to replace it.

I searched a lot, but can't find what type it is.

It's like a 2 pin connector on the motherboard, perhaps to control the battery voltage.

The connector:

[image]

The battery used for the tablet and the cable which will be inserted in this connector:

[image]

Comment: Please measure some dimensions of the connector, especially the pin pitch.

Answer (score 1):

That is a parallel-mate, wire-to-board connector. My [Connector Identification Utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=rectangular_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=parallel_mate_w2b_conn&f=wire_parallel_mate_w2b_conn) lists these:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Hirose - DF63SF
- Hirose - MDF51K
- Hirose - MDF51SU MDF51SY
- JAE - ES9
- JST - ACH
- JST - ACHL
- JST - ADH
- JST - LEH
- JST - LEN
- Molex - Pico-EZmate
- TE - AmpSlim

Of those, the [Molex Pico-EZmate](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=rectangular_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=parallel_mate_w2b_conn&f=wire_parallel_mate_w2b_conn&s=Pico-EZmate) looks like it.[image: Molex Pico-EZ Mate]

{Image source: a composite I made from Digikey images}

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps !!! i appreciate it

Comment: It is common courtesy to upvote a helpful answer and to click "accept" if the answer is correct.